# pip install from GitHub source fails to install dependencies defined in repository's requirements.txt

Tags: python-3.x, pip, requirements

I'm trying to fully install a [Github repository](https://github.com/dpriskorn/OpenAlexAPI) in my package. The item is added properly to my `setup.cfg` file:

```
install_requires =
    requests>=2.27.0, <3.0.0
    rich>=12.3.0, <13.0.0
    pydantic>=1.9.0, <2.0.0
    openalexapi @ git+https://github.com/dpriskorn/OpenAlexAPI.git@master#egg=openalexapi
```

A `pip install -e .` installs `openalexapi` but it does not pull the list of dependencies in their requirements.txt. As such, it fails to install `backoff` and returns the following error:

```py
Python 3.10.0 (default, Oct  7 2021, 04:19:18) [Clang 10.0.0 ]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from openalexapi import works
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from openalexapi import works

File ~/codes/PPPL/promotion-analysis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openalexapi/__init__.py:7, in <module>
      4 import logging
      5 from typing import Optional, List
----> 7 import backoff  # type: ignore
      8 import requests
      9 from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr
```

I know that one can do `pip install -r https://path/to/requirements.txt` but was wondering if there is a way to trigger pulling the dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 1):

When not explicitly (`pip install -r requirements.txt`) asked `pip install` never implicitly uses `requirements.txt`.

Dependencies are listed in wheels' metadata or in source distributions in `setup.cfg`/`setup.py`. And BTW said metadata is generated from `setup.cfg`/`setup.py` which must explicitly read `requirements.txt`.

It's not the case with `openalexapi` code so the only way to use its `requirements.txt` is to do explicitly

```
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dpriskorn/OpenAlexAPI/master/requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. It just seem as though this use isn't well documented. Maybe `pip` will be updated to support this.

Comment: @astrochun "*Maybe `pip` will be updated to support this.*" Not without your help — [a pull request](https://github.com/pypa/pip) or at least [a feature request](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues).

Comment: Fair point. I will consider at least contributing a feature request if one does not already exists

Comment: @astrochun "*…if one does not already exists…*" I failed to find one but there're too many issues so I could missed it (or them).